# Package Installation through script

Tags: centos, centos7

I do understand the following script is installing the packages but what I don't understand is what packages:

```
for package in ${d[@]};
 do
     rpm -ivh --quiet ${!package} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What is `${d[@]}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case 'd' is a name of an array. the '@' in the square brackets means 'each element of the array individually'.

So 'for' loops over each package listed in the array.

About the `${!package}` (taken from the bash manual `man bash` section 'EXPANSION'):

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion.

As you did not post the full script i cannot really see how this works.